# QDialog show is does not happen immediately

Tags: qt

I have a sever client application and in the beginning client loads data from server. I have a dialog showing status of getting data from server (has progress bar). But when I call the function the dialog appears with no contents in it with white background and suddenly changes to completed status.

```
void SystemScreen::loadServerData()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if (NULL != mpDataManagerDlg)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "show progres screen";
        mpDataManagerDlg->showScreen();
    }

    loadData();

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
}

void SystemScreen::loadData()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if (NULL != mpDataManager)
    {
        mpDataManager->loadDataFromServer();
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
}
```

I feel that dialog is displayed only after loadData() function is completed. Is there any alternative to do this?

I used a timer to start

```
QTimer::singleShot(100, this, SLOT(loadData()));
```

But then I have some trouble in getting data. ie data is empty if I read suddenly.

EDIT:

```
void DataManagerDialog::setDefault()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    setProgressBar(0);
    setProgressBarColor(false);

    ui->deptFailButton->hide();
    ui->deptOkButton->hide();
    ui->deptLabel->setStyleSheet("color:gray");
    ui->subGroupFailButton->hide();
    ui->subGroupOkButton->hide();
    ui->subGroupLabel->setStyleSheet("color:gray");
    ui->itemFailButton->hide();
    ui->itemOkButton->hide();
    ui->itemLabel->setStyleSheet("color:gray");
    ui->salesBtnFailButton->hide();
    ui->salesBtnOkButton->hide();
    ui->salesBtnLabel->setStyleSheet("color:gray");

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
}

void DataManagerDialog::alignCenter()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    QWidget *par = parentWidget();
    if (par)
    {
        int x = width()/2;
        int y = height()/2;

        QPoint mid(mapToGlobal(QPoint(x, y)));

        int px = par->width()/2;
        int py = par->height()/2;

        QPoint parMid(mapToGlobal(QPoint(px, py)));

        move(parMid.x()-mid.x(), parMid.y()-mid.y());
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
}

void DataManagerDialog::showScreen()
{
    setDefault();
    alignCenter();
    show();
}
```

Comment: We would need to see more code, particularly showScreen.

Comment: `void DataManagerDialog::alignCenter()
{
    QWidget *par = parentWidget();
    if (par)
    {
        int x = width()/2;
        int y = height()/2;
        QPoint mid(mapToGlobal(QPoint(x, y)));
        int px = par->width()/2;
        int py = par->height()/2;
        QPoint parMid(mapToGlobal(QPoint(px, py)));
        move(parMid.x()-mid.x(), parMid.y()-mid.y());
    }
}

void DataManagerDialog::showScreen()
{
    setDefault();
    alignCenter();
    show();
}`

Comment: You can edit the question to add more code, it doesn't work well in comments.

Comment: You would like to have a non-modal dialog?

Comment: no.. I need it as a modal dialog. i set it in the dialog constructor

Comment: it makes difference?

Comment: @lpapp: It shows dialog immediately but halts there and loadData(); is not invoked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not enter the event loop.

Try to call [QCoreApplication::processEvents()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) from time to time in mpDataManager->loadDataFromServer() to update the GUI.

From the processEvents documentation :

> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation (e.g. copying a file).

### Edit added after getting feedback from the comments

A better approach would be to send signals in your loadDataFromServer() method with the status information and have a slot listen to the signal and update the GUI.

Here a prototype illustrating the idea :

```
void mpDataManagerDlg::loadDataFromServer() {
    while(true) {
        // do some work
        int progress = // some value
        emit updateDialogSignal(progress);
    }
}

// in your dialog class
public slots:
void DataManagerDialog::updateDialog(int progress) {
    // update gui
}
```

More about signals and slots can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: i will try using this

Comment: Using `QCoreApplication::processEvents` is a terrible idea. It should be avoided.

Comment: @thuga: yep, that is exactly what I also wrote earlier, but the OP ignored that, so I removed my comments. It is difficult (for me) to say what the real solution is without seeing more code and more design explanation. In its current form, I personally feel this thread more misleading for future readers than helpful. Now, people will think that if something does not work (even if unclear), use processEvents. With proper design, it is almost always avoidable to mess up with the event loop manually.

Comment: @lpapp I agree. The real problem is obscure in the current context.

Comment: I agree, updated my answer to suggest a better approach

Comment: @ChristopheWeis: you mean to say that I should call `mpDataManagerDlg->showScreen();` within a slot?

Comment: I think you can leave `mpDataManagerDlg->showScreen();` where it is.